# file permission for ls and lsattr

Tags: files, permissions

The file permission for `ls` and `lsattr` are same:

```
debian@debian:~$ ls -al  /usr/bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 147176 Sep 24  2020 /usr/bin/ls
debian@debian:~$ ls -al  /usr/bin/lsattr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14496 Jun  7  2021 /usr/bin/lsattr
```

Why lsattr can't read the flag on file `/etc/shadow`?

```
debian@debian:~$ ls -al  /etc/shadow
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1494 Jul 13 17:46 /etc/shadow
debian@debian:~$ lsattr -al  /etc/shadow
lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on /etc/shadow
```

Comment: at a guess, because `/etc/shadow` doesn't have "other" read permission - the permissions on the executable are mostly irrelevant

Comment: It's probably the lsattr needs to actually read the file whilst you don't have the read permission of that file. The permission of lsattr has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Reasonable research step is to `strace` both commands to see what exactly they (try to) do to `/etc/shadow`. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Bellow it what you can find out about a file with only read and execute permission of its directory, but no permission on the file.

```
#↳ stat  /etc/shadow
  File: /etc/shadow
  Size: 1862            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 393275      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   42/  shadow)
Access: 2023-07-14 21:17:01.226553695 +0100
Modify: 2022-08-26 20:10:51.553518102 +0100
Change: 2022-08-26 20:10:51.553518102 +0100
 Birth: 2022-08-26 20:10:51.553518102 +0100
```

`lsattr` is trying to get additional information.

(there may be other information that modern systems can get. e.g. FACLs)